# PHP BetaAnalyticsDataClient runRealtimeReport empty

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

If I try the following it ends up empty -- Even though when I log into GA Analytics it will show 2 or 3 current active users in the last 30 mins. (which is the data I am trying to get back)

```
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy;

$credentialsPath = 'service-account-credentials.json';
$property_id = 'XXX';
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=" . __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json');

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

$response =  $client->runRealtimeReport ([
    'property' => $property_id,
    'dimensions' => [
        new Dimension(['name' => 'city']),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ]
    )],
]);
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Conversely if I use `runReport()` with a dateRage of `today` -> `today` it also comes back empty, but I feel that's expected as it's not the Real Time API and `today` may be too soon to report.  But by simply changing the `start_date` to `7daysAgo` I get solid, accurate data returned.

```
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => 'today',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [
        new Dimension(['name' => 'city']),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ]
    )
    ],
    'orderBys' => [
        new OrderBy([
            'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                'dimension_name' => 'date', // your dimension here
                'order_type' => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::ALPHANUMERIC
            ]),
            'desc' => false,
        ]),
    ]
]);
```

What am I doing wrong in attempting to glean the "active Users Last 30 Minutes" from Google's AnalyticsData API?  Is it a problem with the release itself [FOUND HERE](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/tree/main/AnalyticsData).  I just need a valid aproach to retrieve real-time data.  has anyone any experience doing this through the PHP API Client?

Comment: check your property id make sure its the same one you are looking at in the web app

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo --  Yes, and verified through running other reports that match up perfectly .. It's so odd.  I can get anything using `runReport()` and `xdaysAgo` --  And it's accurate.  But `runRealtimeReport()` turns up empty (no errors, or suggestions)

Comment: This is still an active question --  I have not been able to get any reasonable answers from Google on this matter either.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

The error i was getting from your code is that it couldnt find the dimension object. So i added `new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension`

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$service_account_key_file_path = "C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials/ServiceAccountCred.json";

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;

try {

    // Authenticate using a keyfile path
    $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
        'credentials' => $service_account_key_file_path
    ]);

    // CHANGE THIS
    $property_id = '250796939';
    $dimensions = [ new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension(['name' => 'city']), ];
    $metrics = [new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric(['name' => 'activeUsers'])];

    $response =  $client->runRealtimeReport ([
        'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
        'dimensions' => $dimensions,
        'metrics' => $metrics,
    ]);

    foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
        foreach ($row->getDimensionValues() as $dimensionValue) {
            print 'Dimension Value: ' . $dimensionValue->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
        }
        foreach ($row->getMetricValues() as $metricValue) {
            print 'Metric Value: ' . $metricValue->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

} catch (\Google\ApiCore\ValidationException $e) {
    printf($e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Linda. That's strange -- I was just receiving an empty array ..  I will check it later today when I move back to that project ...  I'll let you know what happens ...